# ASP.NET: Getting the Current URL via a Web Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, webmethod

I'm trying to retrieve the URL of the current page via a Web Method. The code below works well on a normal C# Method such as the Page_Load but does not work inside a Web Method.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static void UpdateProjectName(string name)
{
        string project_id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
}
```

I'm receiving an empty string ("") as the project_id. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information of the client's previews request to current website you can use the UrlReferrer as follow:

```
//To get the Absolute path of the URI use this
string myPreviousAbsolutePath = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;

//To get the Path and Query of the URI use this
string myPreviousPathAndQuery = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string mywebmethod()
{
string myUrl=  HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.ToString();
return parameters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do next code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static void UpdateProjectName(string name)
{
        string project_id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
}
```

`Url` is just object, that's why it returns empty value to you. `AbsoluteUri` will give a full URL of current page. Example: http://yourweb.site/Admin.aspx?id=15&time=yesterday

Comment: Nope. This gives me the address of the current Web Method URL. I got this => "http://localhost:19568/CreateProject.aspx/UpdateProjectName"